# Loop a function in Python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

How to loop a function for the below data set.

I can only use the function for specific user by

```
df =sorteddf[sorteddf.user ==1]
function(df)
```

The data set contains multiple users

```
time_slot              User     Location
2017-10-27 15:00:00     1       766
2017-10-27 15:45:00     1       902
2017-10-27 16:00:00     1       902
2017-10-27 10:45:00     2       902
2017-10-27 12:45:00     2       902 
2017-10-27 16:30:00     2       902
```

How to use the function for all the users in the dataframe and print the output of all the users.

```
time_slot              User    Location
2017-10-27 00:00:00     1.0     766.0   
2017-10-27 00:15:00     1.0     961.0   
2017-10-27 00:30:00     1.0     56.0    
2017-10-27 00:45:00     1.0     542.0   
2017-10-27 01:00:00     1.0     324.0   
2017-10-27 01:15:00     1.0     526.0   
2017-10-27 01:30:00     1.0     258.0   
2017-10-27 01:45:00     1.0     532.0
```

Comment: let me know if my answer helps

Comment: @makaros PLEASE deleted these comments, and never self-advertise again!!

Comment: @makaros You shall know, you got 7k rep

Comment: can you post the function too? `sorteddf` ...?

Comment: @anky_91 sorteddf is nothing but the name of my df. Let's assume the function is any random function. The output should be like all the users in the column should pass through the function and print output data of all the users.

Comment: See my updated answer. It works fine for me using python 2.7.

Answer (score -1):

For every user you could create a loop as follows:

```
users = sorteddf['User'].unique()
for user in users:
    print('Output for user {}'.format(user))
    function(sorteddf[sorteddf.User == user])
```

Is this something you were looking for?

Comment: Not exactly. You can find the detailed explanation above

Comment: then just pass over df = sorteddf[sorteddf.User == user] to your function. Shouldnt that work?

Comment: No that's not working. can you write the code in detail?

Comment: I edited the answer. Check if this yields the results you are looking for

Answer (score -1):

Define the user list and then use a `for` loop to apply your function:

An example using `function` that calculates the sum of the Location variable.

```
def function(sorteddf, i):
    print(sorteddf[sorteddf.User==i]['Location'].sum())

users = sorteddf['User'].unique()

for i in users:
    function(sorteddf , i)
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: It prints only the last user but not all the user. Can you please verify

Comment: Try print(function(df)) ?

Comment: I do not understand the downvoting. I have provided an example that works fine.

Comment: @Krush23 see my updated answer and the obtained output (image).